# Write entry form details to text file

Tags: php, html, forms, file

I am trying to input the data from a submission form into a text file using PHP code. Im struggling to create the php file to receive the data below and save it in a text file, preferably opening it up in a new tab.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Entry Form</title>
</head>
<body>
<form method="post" action="<?php echo $PHP_SELF;?>">
Login Code:<input type="text" size="12" maxlength="36" name="Lcode"><br />
First Name:<input type="text" size="12" maxlength="12" name="Fname"><br />
Last Name:<input type="text" size="12" maxlength="36" name="Lname"><br />
Gender: <br />
Male:<input type="radio" value="Male" name="gender"><br />
Female:<input type="radio" value="Female" name="gender"
```

Comment: It is not really clear what you mean by struggling. What happens if you submit the form?

Comment: when i submit the form, i have it so it takes me to another page that simply says thanks for submitting. I just want to know how to make it appear on a text file so the entered details are displayed.

Answer (score 0):

After you submitted the form you can grab the form data and write it file_put_contents()

function is explained here
http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php

You are submitting to the same page as the form so i suggest you check the post array then grab the data and write it to the file:

```
$file = 'content.txt';
$content.= $_POST["Fname"]."\n";
$content.= $_POST["Lname"]."\n";
```

etc...

```
 // Write the content to the file
    file_put_contents($file, $content);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

HTML

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Entry Form</title>
</head>
<body>
<form method="post" action="">
Login Code:<input type="text" size="12" maxlength="36" name="Lcode"><br />
First Name:<input type="text" size="12" maxlength="12" name="Fname"><br />
Last Name:<input type="text" size="12" maxlength="36" name="Lname"><br />
Gender: <br />
Male:<input type="radio" value="Male" name="gender"><br />
Female:<input type="radio" value="Female" name="gender"></br>
<input type="submit" value="Submit" name="submit">
</form>
```

PHP

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $fp = fopen('myfile.txt', 'a+');//This will create a file named myfile.txt in your application base path
    unset($_POST['submit']);
    foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
        fwrite($fp,$key.' = '.$value."\n");
    }
    fclose($fp);
}
?>
```